# Pointwise convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ has a uniformly continuous derivative. We define $\ f_n: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R  $  by

$$\ f_n(x) = n \left( f \left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)\right) $$

Find a pointwise convergence $\ f_n$. Prove that the sequence $\ f_n$ converges uniformly to its limit.

Comment: Do you mean "*has* a uniformly continuous derivative"?

Comment: yes, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you done so far?

**Hint:** for the pointwise convergence, write 
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{f(x+h_n)-f(x)}{h_n}
$$
with $h_n=\frac{1}{n}\to 0^+$

Comment: Maybe it is better to write $h_n=1/n$.

Comment: so pointwise convergence:
∀x∈D:∀ϵ∈R>0:∃N∈R:∀n>N:|fn(x)−f(x)|<ϵ  


$
f_n(x) = \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})- \frac{n+1}{n} f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}
$
What should I do next?

Comment: Where does the $\frac{n-1}{n}$ factor come from — and what are you trying to do? It looks as if you assume that $(f_n)$ converges to $f$; this is *not* the case.

 Look at the original expression (and my answer — I only rewrote it). Also, try to recall the definition of the derivative $f'(x)$ as a limit.

Comment: I just did it |fn(x)−f(x)|<ϵ. The definition of the derivative f'(x) will be as you wrote it. But I don't get it how it could help me.

Comment: Because $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f'$. As I said, you appear to think that the limit is $f$ (that's why, I reckon, you "do $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$" (?)). But the limit of the sequence is __not__ $f$.

Comment: Why $\ f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $\ f' $? I don't understand it, I'm sorry. Could you write the solution with theorems? I'll be so grateful.

Comment: Convergence pointwise of $(f_n)$ means that there exists a function $g$ such that, for every fixed $x_0$, $$f_n(x_0)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} g(x_0)$$

Here, for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, you have
$$f_n(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0)}{1/n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} f'(x_0)$$
(by definition of the derivative of $f$) proving that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $g=f'$.

Comment: Ahh I see. 
Could I use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem ? And how can I prove the second part?

Comment: You don't need anything else (no theorem) for the first part; this is sufficient (it proves that $f_n\to f'$ pointwise).
Now,for the second part, the only possible _uniform_ limit is $f'$ (as if $f_n\to g$ uniformly, in particular $f_n\to g$ pointwise; and the limit is unique, so $g=f'$). So you must prove that $f_n\to f'$ uniformly.
For that, the hypothesis that $f'$ is uniformly continuous (u.c.) has (and will) play a major role. Start by writing down what it means for a function to be u.c., and see how you can use it to prove that $|f_n(x)-f'(x)|$ can be upperbounded independently of $x$.

Comment: ∀ϵ>0:∃δ>0:(x,y∈I,|x−y|<δ⟹|f'(x)−f'(y)|<ϵ how to use it?

Comment: I've been lost.

Comment: ? Did you even try? (given the time of your messages, not for long)

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm just tired. Yes I'm thinking about this all the time but this is the first exercise like that I've ever done. I just know the single therems but I can't compile it in one solution

Comment: For the second part, use the mean value theorem. More previsely, fix any $\epsilon > 0$; and let $\eta$ be the corresponding value wrt the uniform convergence of $f'$. Further, let $N$ be the first integer such that $\frac{1}{N} \leq \eta$. We hereafter consider only integers $n\geq N$.

For any $x$ in $\mathbb R$, there exists $c_n=c_n(x)$ such that $\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}=f'(c_n)$ (mean value theorem). Thus, $f_n(x) = f'(c_n)$.
In particular,
$$



(__currently writing__)

Comment: In particular,
$$
\forall n\geq N,\forall x,\ |f_n(x)-f'(x)|=|f'(c_n(x))-f'(x)| \leq \epsilon
$$
because $|c_n(x)-x|\leq 1/n\leq 1/N \leq \eta$.

This shows that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N_\epsilon$, $\forall n\geq N_\epsilon$ $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f'(x)| \leq \epsilon$; in other terms, 

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)-f'(x)| \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$